# @PutMapping doesn't work in my SpringBoot project

Tags: html, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

I've tried to implement TodoList editing into my GetTodoController and it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Todo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/todo/operation.css}">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Edit your Todo!</h2>
    <form th:method="PUT" th:action="@{/todo/edit/{id}(id=${list.id})}" th:object="${list}">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name">
        <span style="color: #ba6a65" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}"></span>
        <br>
        <label for="description">Description: </label>
        <textarea th:field="*{description}" id="description">Enter text here...</textarea>
        <span style="color: #ba6a65" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('description')}" th:errors="*{description}"></span>
        <br>
        <label for="deadline">Deadline: </label>
        <input type="datetime-local" th:field="*{deadline}" id="deadline">
        <span style="color: #ba6a65" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('deadline')}" th:errors="*{description}"></span>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@RequestMapping("/todo/edit/{id}")
@Controller
public class UpdateTodoController {
    private final TodoListRepository todoListRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UpdateTodoController(TodoListRepository todoListRepository) {
        this.todoListRepository = todoListRepository;
    }

    @ModelAttribute(name = "list")
    public TodoList todoList(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return todoListRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String getUpdateTodo(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return "todo/update";
    }

    @PutMapping
    public String putUpdateTodo(@PathVariable Long id, @ModelAttribute(name = "list") @Valid TodoList todoList, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) return "todo/update";
        System.out.println(todoList);
        todoListRepository.update(todoList);
        return "redirect:/todo";
    }
}
```

I've changed @PutMapping to @PostMapping and th:method="PUT" to th:method="POST" and everything has worked, but it is conceptually wrong, cuz of @PostMapping - adding new, @PutMapping - updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PUT mappings to work with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf you need to set the following property in application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true
```

This will enable the hidden method filter and when used with th:method the filter will allow PUT methods to be processed correctly.